# How to do this recursion method to print out every 3 letters from a string on a separate line?

Tags: python

I'm making a method that takes a string, and it outputs parts of the strings on separate line according to a window.

For example:

I want to output every 3 letters of my string on separate line.

```
Input : "Advantage"
Output:
    Adv
    ant
    age

Input2: "23141515"
Output: 
     231
     141
     515
```

My code:

```
def print_method(input):
    mywindow = 3
    start_index = input[0]
    if(start_index == input[len(input)-1]):
        exit()
    print(input[1:mywindow])
    printmethod(input[mywindow:])
```

However I get a runtime error.... Can someone help?

Comment: `printmethod` on your last line should be `print_method`. What is the exact error you're getting? I also think you mean to print from `0:mywindow` (or just `:mywindow`) not from `1`. Not sure why you're comparing the first character in `input` to the last one and then exiting if they're equal? Perhaps you mean to exit if `input` is an empty string?

Comment: I feel like ``if(start_index == input[len(input)-1])`` is a quite confusing way (and wrong way) to check `ìf len(input)==1``

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're trying to get. Here's what I changed:

1. Renamed `input` to `input_str`. `input` is a keyword in Python, so it's not good to use for a variable name.
2. Added the missing `_` in the recursive call to `print_method`
3. Print from `0:mywindow` instead of `1:mywindow` (which would skip the first character). When you start at `0`, you can also just say `:mywindow` to get the same result.
4. Change the exit statement (was that `sys.exit`?) to be a `return` instead (probably what is wanted) and change the `if` condition to be to return once an empty string is given as the input. The last string printed might not be of length 3; if you want this, you could use instead `if len(input_str) < 3: return`

```py
def print_method(input_str):
    mywindow = 3
    if not input_str: # or you could do if len(input_str) == 0
        return
    print(input_str[:mywindow])
    print_method(input_str[mywindow:])
```

Answer (score 0):

*edit* sry missed the title: if that is not a learning example for recursion you shouldn't use recursion cause it is less efficient and slices the list more often.

```
def chunked_print (string,window=3):
    for i in range(0,len(string) // window + 1): print(string[i*window:(i+1)*window])
```

This will work if the window size doesn't divide the string length, but print an empty line if it does. You can modify that according to your needs

Comment: I mean yes, but that won't really get this user to understand why his code was wrong, and how to do recursion.

Comment: he didnt say it needed to be done with recursion, recursion is less efficient because it creates more list slices.

Comment: Technically, he said "How to do this *recursion method* ..." (emphasis added). But yes, it is reasonable to mention that using recursion here is less efficient. This might just be a toy example that he's doing to learn about recursion, though, which is a useful technique in general.

Comment: you are right my bad didnt ntice the title and just went purely off of question